# How to have a loading icon between react router route transitions?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Trying to get the preloader to show, fade out, and then show the new route. How to do this? Right now the page is flashing, then the preloader shows, and fades out to the new route.

I'm trying to use useLocation with useEffect(() => {...}, [location]) but it's causing the flash.

At the router level I have it add a loading class to the body so the preloader shows. Once the route component is mounted I'm removing that class. It seems like the useEffect that triggers on location change is getting called after the route render though.

Comment: Take a look at useHistory

Comment: How does that help? useHistory is for pushing routes. useLocation is for detecting route changes.

Comment: Can you add an example of your code so it's easier to answer your question?

Comment: Actually, I think I got it! useEffect hooked into history.listen and changing on history change. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright so this seems to have fixed it here is the code I had before.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.remove('loaded');

    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    const currentPath = location.pathname + location.search;
    analytics.sendPageview(currentPath);

    setTimeout(function () {
      document.body.classList.add("loaded");
    }, 1000);

  }, [location]);
```

Here is the code I switched to that fixed it.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return history.listen(location => {
      document.body.classList.remove('loaded');

      setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.classList.add("loaded");
      }, 1000);
    })
  }, [history])
```